# CodeBuild Error: Trusted Principals Don't Belong to the Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to edit an existing CodeBuild project's source. I have added an Actor ID in the filter group. When I try to save, I receive:

`The trusted principals don't belong to the service.`

I have tried other changes as well - I always receive the same error. I am an admin with full access to the project. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was seeing the same error, in my case unchecking the checkbox:

"Allow AWS CodeBuild to modify this service role so it can be used with this build project"

under "Service role permissions" allowed me to complete the edit from within the management console.

Comment: Yep - this worked  but I don't know why this setting was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the CLI. The command I used was `aws codebuild update-webhook`. It worked fine, don't know why it didn't using the console.